# Как должна правильно выглядеть структура много файловой программа C++?

Tags: c++, clion

Я работаю в clion, и, при создании файла класса, среда создаёт .h файл и .cpp файл. Они содержат следующее:

**A.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED3_A_H
#define UNTITLED3_A_H


class A {
public:
    int test = 1;

};


#endif
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
```

Я написал реализацию класса A в заголовочном файле, удалил .cpp и программа заработала.
Тогда зачем среда создаёт .cpp файл? Что Я должен там описывать? Правильно ли я сделал, что написал реализацию в заголовочном файле? Так же хочу попросить рекомендации при написании много файловых программ на данном языке программирования.

Программа запускается без **A.cpp**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
int main() {
    A a = A();
    std::cout << a.test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему вам нужно начать с того, чтобы разобраться как работает компилятор. Вы наверняка просто не компилируете ваш cpp файл с реализацией

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Что вы имеете ввиду? Если вы думаете, что при компиляции файл просто игнорируется, то нет. У меня есть простенькая переменная в оригинальном классе, я создаю экземпляр класса в основной функции и вывожу эту переменную. То есть файл не игнорируется компилятором.

Comment: в таком случае минимальный пример в студию

Comment: Создание переменной никак не виляет на то, какие .cpp файлы компилирует компилятор.

Comment: @user7860670 Я это понимаю. Привёл такой пример, чтобы показать, что компилятор не игнорирует файлы.

Comment: @llollcat и что это? Ну да, она запускается без A.cpp, а она что, не должна работать без этого файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбиение программы на файлы помогает подчеркнуть ее логическую структуру, облегчает ее понимание другими и позволяет компилятору обеспечить эту логическую структуру. Когда единицей компиляции является файл, весь он должен быть заново перекомпилирован при внесении изменений (не зависимо от того, насколько они малы) в него или в другой файл, от которого
он зависит.  Ваша программа не нуждается в деталях реализации, поэтому  их вы выносите в `.cpp файл`, дабы обеспечить  вышесказанное. Конечно, при маленьком размере заголовочного файла(пару классов и пару функций), реализацию  тривиальных классов и функций можно не разделять и прямо написать в заголовочном файле, но, обычно заголовочные файлы бывают большими, и реализации бывают далеко не тривиальными...

P.S.  Во многих учебниках об этом написано   более подробно...

Comment: Один из вопросов: "Правильно ли я сделал, что написал реализацию в заголовочном файле?". На сколько я понял из вашего ответа, всё таки реализация не должна находиться в заголовочном файле, так?

Comment: Читайте ответ внимательней. Строчка:  *"Конечно, при маленьком размере заголовочного файла(пару классов и пару функций)..."`*